# Think Or Swim on 19.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.04

I was able to get thinkorswim running just fine, however I did not get a desktop starting point.  Does anyone know the procedure for starting thinkorswim now that it is installed?  I have been playing around with it for quite some time and nothing has worked.

Comment: What is thinkorswim? Where can we download it?

Comment: https://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/install.html  It is a brokerage platform

Answer (score 2):

I found it in the directory

```
/usr/local/thinkorswim
```

and here is how to start it from terminal:

```
sudo /usr/local/thinkorswim/thinkorswim
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a desktop launcher all you have to do is create a .desktop file for your programme.

You could start by creating a copy of an already existing .desktop file.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/apport-gtk.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/thinkorswim.desktop
```

Then modify the copied file accordingly, using your preferred editor. Change the name and especially the exec line to point to where the app is installed.

Finally you need to make the .desktop file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/thinkorswim.desktop
```